# Aligning a system of linear equations

Tags: equations, systeme

I want to figure out how I can align a system of linear equations very nicely.

At the moment I am using the following command:

```
\systeme{x_1=2r + s -t,x_2= r, x_3=-2s +2t, x_4=s, x_5=t}
```

But this gives me something ugly in staircase form, like:

[image]

Any way I could fix it so the `x_i`'s are all at the left side, nicely underneath each other, and possibly with the equation signs also aligned?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openany]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{systeme,mathtools}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{relsize}
\newcommand\md{\ }

\begin{document}

\systeme{x_1=2r + s -t,x_2= r, x_3=-2s +2t, x_4=s, x_5=t}

\end{document}
```

Comment: normally one uses `align` or one of its variants from `amsmath` but it is impossible to comment on your code as `\systeme` is not a standard plain or latex command and you give no indication of its definition.

Comment: I'm using TexnicCenter, and I just use the package: \usepackage{systeme,mathtools}. There's no special definition, it's just standard.

Comment: I need to have \systeme because I want that there appears an array on the left to make it clear to the reader that it is a system of equations.

Comment: Please edit your post to show a complete, compilable document starting with `\documentclass...` and ending with `\end{document}`. That way, people will not have to spend time gradually extracting every essential detail from you, only to find they overlooked something after spending time posting an answer.

Comment: You have given no indication of what `\systeme` is, I had never heard of the command searching around suggests you are using a package of the same name and using latex, but you really should provide a complete example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` by editing the above question

Comment: @Kamil it is not standard at all, there are thousands of packages, you can not expect to just mention some command defined in some contributed package without saying what package you are using and expect people to recognise it.

Comment: How do I enter a code here from my LaTeX document? It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: make a small (6 or 7 line) latex document, add it to your question then indent by 4 spaces by highlighting and clicking the `{}` button in the editor which will make it a code section, as I did in my edits to your one line example

Comment: @Kamil but the posted code doesn't help, it needs to be a complete document and needs to demonstrate the problem, so it doesn't need all the theorem definitions etc but it should use \systeme and should have \end{document}

Comment: Is it possible to somehow import the output I get in LaTeX into here, so I can show what's actually wrong?

Comment: You need to add it as an image, I did it, but I also had to fix your example, as it still was not a document that could be run.

Comment: Use `\systeme*`

Comment: It is not clear now what your question is. The package documentation is French which I find difficult, but it seems the main point of the command is to align the coefficients of different variables and as your system uses a different variable on each row they are placed in separate columns. If you do not want that then it seems you do not want this command.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! That fixed it. Do you maybe know how I can reduce the white space between each linear equation?

Comment: This is NOT a MWE.

Comment: Note: You can translate PDF's using Google Translate. It's a pain, but better than trying to read the French documentation if you don't know French.
https://translate.google.com/?sl=fr&tl=en&op=docs

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The command to use for this is `\systeme*`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openany]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

I want to figure out how I can align a system of linear equations very nicely.
At the moment I am using the following command:
\[
\systeme*{x_1=2r + s -t,x_2= r, x_3=-2s +2t, x_4=s, x_5=t}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

By setting the value of `\syslineskipcoeff` you can modify the spacing; the default value is 1.25:

```
\[
\syslineskipcoeff{1}
\systeme*{x_1=2r + s -t,x_2= r, x_3=-2s +2t, x_4=s, x_5=t}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! Appreciate it.

Comment: The letters $r, s, t$ aren't aligned.

Comment: @Bernard That's not required by the OP

Comment: @egreg: it's one of the main intrests in `systeme`. Else a simple `align*` environment would do the job. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Bernard If one replace ``systeme*`` by ``systeme`` the letters $r, s, t$ will be aligned. Do you agree with me?

Answer (score 22):

Here's a solution that uses only the `array` package and an `array` environment. In case you're curious about what's going on in the preamble of the `array` environment:

- The four columns that contain variables are of type `r`
- To get the correct spacing around the `=` symbols and the `+` and `-` signs, the amount of intercolumn whitespace (governed by the length parameter `\arraycolsep`) is first set to `0pt`.

  - The `=` symbols are inserted automatically; the directive `@{{}={}}` tells LaTeX to treat `=` as an object of type `mathrel`.
  - The directives `>{{}}c<{{}}` tell LaTeX to center-set the column contents (which will be either `+`, `-`, or blank) and to treat them as objects of type `mathbin`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openany]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\[
\left\{
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{array}{ r @{{}={}} r  >{{}}c<{{}} r  >{{}}c<{{}}  r }
x_1 & 2r &+&  s &-&  t \\
x_2 &  r               \\
x_3 &    &-& 2s &+& 2t \\ 
x_4 &    & &  s        \\
x_5 &    & &    & &  t \\
\end{array}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14):

The `systeme` command is designed for the "matrix-like" (if you can't tell, I'm an engineer, not a mathematician) portion of the system to be on the left-hand side, not the right-hand side.

If you can accept a simple LHS->RHS swap of your input, `systeme` works out of the box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}
\systeme{2r + s -t=x_1, r=x_2, -2s +2t=x_3, s=x_4, t=x_5}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is likely possible to create a new command in the spirit of `\systeme{}` with the aligned and unaligned sides reversed, but the code is above my head. `;-)`

Answer (score 9):

A simple hack with the `aligned` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ \left\{\begin{aligned}x_1 & = \\x_2 & =\\x_3 & =\\x_4 & =\\x_5 & =\\ \end{aligned}\sysdelim. . \systeme[rst]{2r + s -t , r , -2s +2t, s, t}\right.
 \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using a TABstack.  In this case the "Center" of `\tabbedCenterstack` refers to vertical centering, the `[r]` refers to horizontal right alignment of each column, `\stackMath` processes the data in math mode, and `\TABbinary` inserts a `{}` prior to and following each cell, so as to give the `+` and `-` the proper horizontal spacing.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openany]{report}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\left\{
\TABbinary\tabbedCenterstack[r]{
x_1 =& 2r &+&  s &-&  t \\
x_2 =&  r               \\
x_3 =&    &-& 2s &+& 2t \\ 
x_4 =&    & &  s        \\
x_5 =&    & &    & &  t
}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. What would you say are the main differences between using `\TABbinary\tabbedCenterstack[r]` and using an `array` environment?

Comment: @Mico 0pt intercolumn gap is default in `tabbed...` stacks; Center-stacks are long stacks, thus all lines are forced to be equal baselineskips apart (though short stacks are more akin to `array`s in this regard); interrow vertical baselineskip is easily set with `\setstackgap{L}{length}`; more options for how to automatically treat math operators with `\TABbinary`, `\TABbinaryRight`, and `\TABbinaryLeft`; `\fixTABwidth{T}` is available to force all columns to equal width;  while centerstacks are vertically centered, stacks and understacks are not, which is often very useful.