# Aligning system of equations with zero coefficients

Tags: equations, align

How to type a system of equations of the following form aligning the same variables when they do have zero coefficients. 
[image]

I looked at few posts including [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220682/aligning-a-system-of-linear-equations) but wasn't successful. Appreciate any help in getting this done. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220693/121799).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}
\sysdelim..\systeme{x_2      +2x_3          +2x_4         -2x_5    =1,
x_1                +3x_3                   +4x_5    =5, 
-x_1         +3x_2       +3x_3                   -10x_5    =4}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @marmot. Can you tell me how to get rid of the curly braces to the left.

Comment: @Hagridd Brackets removed.

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of variety, here's an implementation that uses [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220712/189103) from the post you originally linked only using `array`.  Admittedly, it's not quite as elegant as the solution marmot provided. However, its output is exactly the same as what's produced by `\systeme`. Observe that both answers produce output that's more tightly spaced than what's shown in the screenshot you posted. The `array`-based solution is also somewhat more general than what's produced by `\systeme`, in the sense that it can handle fairly arbitrary variable names.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for "\newcolumntype" macro
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{{}}c<{{}} }

\usepackage{systeme}
\sysdelim..

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.21} % optional
\begin{array}{r *{5}{Cr}}
         & &  x_2 &+& 2x_3 &+& 2x_4 &-&  2x_5 &=& 1 \\
     x_1 & &      &+& 3x_3 & &      &+&  4x_5 &=& 5 \\
    -x_1 &+& 3x_2 &+& 3x_3 & &      &-& 10x_5 &=& 4
\end{array}
\]

%% for comparison, @marmot's answer which uses "\systeme"
\[
\systeme{      x_2 +2x_3 +2x_4 -2x_5 =1,
         x_1       +3x_3       +4x_5 =5, 
        -x_1 +3x_2 +3x_3      -10x_5 =4}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for the variety.

Comment: +1 for the variety. ;-)