# How to use \alignedat? (Aligning a system of linear equations)

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment

I've seen the post on [aligning a system of equations with `systeme` and `array`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220682/aligning-a-system-of-linear-equations); is there a way to do something similar with `alignedat`?

I am using KaTeX and it has `array` (but without `arraycolsep` support at present) and `align` and  `alignedat`. I can get pretty close to what I want with `alignedat`, but I don't understand how it works.

[Page 8 of the amsmath user's guide](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex-dev/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf#page=12) mentions `alignat` and there's a later reference to `alignedat` with no explanation of how it differs from `alignat`... can anyone help?

Here is a sample document I am using to help understand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme, array, amsmath}

\begin{document}
\systeme*{
  X_\alpha=\frac{2}{3}X_A - \frac{1}{3}X_B- \frac{1}{3}X_C,
  X_\beta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}X_B - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}X_C
}

\par

This is the best I can do within LaTeX:

\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{array}{ r @{{}={}} r  >{{}}c<{{}} cr  >{{}}c<{{}}  cr }
  X_\alpha &\frac{2}{3}X_A &-& \frac{1}{3}&X_B       &-& \frac{1}{3}&X_C \\[2pt]
  X_\beta  &               & &\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&X_B &-& \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&X_C
\end{array}
\]

With no arraycolsep:

\[
\begin{array}{ r @{{}={}} r  >{{}}c<{{}} cr  >{{}}c<{{}}  cr }
  X_\alpha &\frac{2}{3}X_A &-& \frac{1}{3}&X_B       &-& \frac{1}{3}&X_C \\[2pt]
  X_\beta  &               & &\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&X_B &-& \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&X_C
\end{array}
\]

Alignedat:

\[
\begin{alignedat}{4}
   X_\alpha &=\frac{2}{3}X_A &-& \frac{1}{3}X_B &- \frac{1}{3}&X_C \\
   X_\beta &= && \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}X_B &- \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&X_C
\end{alignedat}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The point, I think, of `alignedat` is that it works *exactly* like `alignat`, except it is to be used as a building block within other math displays.

Comment: ok so the argument is the number of pairs of right-aligned and left-aligned columns?